# Unable to fetch the value inside the table description list <dd>S</dd> and <dd>Green</dd> using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In chropath when clicked on value 'S' inside tag  it displays that "value must be inside an iFrame from different source"

Also when tried to fetch it I am getting empty value [] while Asserting.

Exception Iam getting:

```
12:09:2020 - 23:06:52 [main] ERROR com.magento.AddToCart - expected [XS] but found []
12:09:2020 - 23:06:52 [main] ERROR com.magento.AddToCart - org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
```

Code I tried for fetching and asserting:

```
for (WebElement swatch :
                    swatch_options) {
    cart_swatch.add(swatch.findElement(By.xpath("//dl/dd")).getText());
}

for (int swatch = 0; swatch < cart_swatch.size(); swatch++) {
    Assert.assertEquals(**cart_swatch.get(swatch)**, ProductModel.getProduct_swatches().get(swatch));
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<dl class="item-options" style="" xpath="1">
<dt>Size</dt>
<dd style="">
                                                                    S                                                     </dd>
<dt>Color</dt>
<dd>
                                                                    Green                                                            </dd>
</dl>
```

When tried to print the "innerHTML" I got this inside the dd tag:

```
<!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
<span data-bind="text: option.value">M</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Iam not getting the value inside the tag dd.
Would be great if i get to know how.

Thank you.

Comment: Your xpath looks incorrect. Give try with xpath as `//dl//dd` , kindly note double slash before `dd` compare to your single slash

Comment: Actually the <dt><dd> are under <dl>. <dd> is not inside <dt>
So when I find using //dl/dd the proper element is highlighted.(i.e, <dd>)

Comment: `/` single slash represent immediate child element, while `//` double slash looks for any child element. Is your issue resolve?